# how to call a java function from javascript using JSF

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, jakarta-ee

I'm using JSF2.0 and trying to call a java function from javascript but couldn't achieve this.
I've a jsp with datatable, where 2 of my columns(Material and Desc) fetch data from the popup jsp.Now the user enters data in 2 other fields(Unit and Qty), taking these 4 as input parameters I have a java function which returns the rest of the values (NetPrice and NetTax in my example)
How can I call the java method here such that I can get the values to my jsp's(test.jsp) text fields.Here is the code snippet of my trail

### test.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
        function testPrevSibling(buttonElement) {
            try {
                // alert(buttonElement);
                var inputText = buttonElement.previousSibling;
                while (inputText.nodeType!=1)
                {
                    inputText =inputText.previousSibling;
                }
                //      alert(inputText.id);
                return inputText.id;
            } catch(ex) {
                alert("bad " + ex);
            }
        }
        function testNextSibling(buttonElement) {
            try {
                // alert(buttonElement);
                var inputText = buttonElement.nextSibling;
                while (inputText.nodeType!=1)
                {
                    inputText =inputText.nextSibling;
                }
                // alert("next sibling-->"+inputText.innerHTML);
                return inputText;
            } catch(ex) {
                alert("bad " + ex);
            }
        }

        // var inputId;
        function popUp(URL,buttonRef) {
            var inputId = testPrevSibling(buttonRef);

            //     alert(inputId);
            day = new Date();
            id = day.getTime();
            URL = URL+"?inputId="+inputId;
            eval("page" + id + " = window.open(URL, '" + id + "', 'toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,location=1,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=1,width=250,height=800 left = 630,top = 502');");
        }
        function getDetails(inputId,matVal,desc){
            var inputRef = document.getElementById(inputId);
            var tdRef = inputRef.parentNode;
            var tdNextRef = testNextSibling(tdRef);
      //      alert("td Ref-->"+tdRef+"td next Ref-->"+tdNextRef);
            var descRef = tdNextRef.firstChild;
        //    alert("Child ref-->"+descRef);
        //    alert("Current JSP-->"+matVal+"input Id-->"+inputId+"desc-->"+desc);
            document.getElementById(inputId).value = matVal;
            descRef.value = desc;
        }
    </script>
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <f:view>
        <h:form>
            <br>
            <h:panelGrid  bgcolor="#9AC8E6" width="100%">
                <h:dataTable id="d" value="#{SalesCreate.orderBean.itemList}" var="iBean" bgcolor="#9AC8E6" border="10" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="3" rows="10" width="100%" dir="LTR" frame="hsides" rules="all" >

                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText style=""value="Material" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:inputText id="mat" value="#{iBean.material}" > </h:inputText>
                        <h:commandButton value="..." onclick="javascript:popUp('MaterialList.jsp',this)" > </h:commandButton>
                        <h:commandButton style="display:none" value="..." onclick="" > </h:commandButton>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText style=""value="Description" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:inputText id="desc" value="#{iBean.description}" > </h:inputText>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText style=""value="Unit" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:inputText value="#{iBean.unit}" > </h:inputText>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Quantity"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:inputText value="#{iBean.quantity}"> </h:inputText>
                        <h:form>
                            <h:commandLink value="get Pricing" action="#{SalesCreate.pricingForQuotation}" >
                                <f:param name="mat" value="#{iBean.material}" />
                                <f:param name="unt" value="#{iBean.unit}" />
                                <f:param name="qty" value="#{iBean.quantity}" />
                            </h:commandLink> </h:form>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText style=""value="Unit Price" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:inputText value="#{iBean.netPrice}" > </h:inputText>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText style=""value="Total Price" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:inputText value="#{iBean.netTax}" > </h:inputText>
                    </h:column>
                </h:dataTable>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </f:view>
</body>
```

### popup.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
        function testNextSibling(buttonElement) {
            try {
                // alert(buttonElement);
                var inputText = buttonElement.nextSibling;
                while (inputText.nodeType!=1)
                {
                    inputText =inputText.nextSibling;
                }
                alert("next sibling-->"+inputText.innerHTML);
                return inputText.innerHTML;
            } catch(ex) {
                alert("bad " + ex);
            }
        }
        function gup( name )
        {
            name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
            var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
            var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
            var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
            if( results == null )
                return "";
            else
                return results[1];
        }
        function setMaterialValue(mat,matNum){
            //   alert("mat " + mat);
            var desc = testNextSibling(mat);
            //   alert("Description-->"+desc);
            var inputId = gup("inputId");
            window.opener.getDetails(inputId,matNum,desc);
            //  window.opener.document.getElementById(mat).value;
            window.close();
        }
    </script>
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<f:view>
    <body>
        <h:dataTable id="datatbl" value="#{SalesCreate.inquiryMaterialList}" var="materialList"  bgcolor="#9AC8E6" border="10" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="3" rows="3000" width="100%" dir="LTR" rules="all">

            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText style=""value="Material" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:form>
                    <h:commandLink style="" id="materialId" value="#{materialList.material}" onclick="javascript:setMaterialValue(this,#{materialList.material})" ></h:commandLink>
                    <h:outputText style="display:none" value="#{materialList.description}"></h:outputText>
                </h:form>
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText style=""value="Description" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:form>
                    <h:commandLink style="" value="#{materialList.description}" onclick="javascript:setDescriptionValue(#{materialList.description})" ></h:commandLink></h:form>
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
    </body>
</f:view>
```

I've tried using a commandLink but I want it to be done when the textfield looses its focus or something similar

Comment: This is truly possible. Only the functional requirement is pretty vague so that your question is not answerable. *When* exactly would you like to call the JSF action method? When some element retrieves focus? When some element get clicked? When some element get blurred? When the user walks away from the PC? When the PC explodes? Etc. More detail please.

Comment: @BalusC: Nice take :). But I believe even that would be an AJAX call, isn't it?

Comment: @Adeel: OP is using JSF 2.0. It should be as easy as putting a `<f:ajax>` tag *somewhere*.

Comment: @BalusC: Cent percent agreement. Usually, its good to describe whats happening behind the scene. For example, just because JSP is a tag-like language few folks think that it runs on client, and confuse JSP with JavaScript very often.

Comment: Sorry my question was incomplete when posted...I've now edited it properly..kindly help me out now..

Answer (score 1):

```
   <h:inputText value="#{yourbackingBean.first}">
                <f:ajax event="blur" render="cm" listener="#{yourbackingBean.caluculate}"/>
     </h:inputText>
     h:inputText value="#{yourbackingBean.second}" id="cm"/>
          </h:form>
```

- Here event can be your choice like
  blur,change,keyup,keydown
  etc.........

  Listener is the method    to be
  called when particular event
  triggered.

  Here caluclate is the    method
  consist of logic to populate
  remaining fields in your jsp.

**your Backing Bean**

```
          private int first=1;
          private int second=1;
    //Getters and Setters
     public void caluculate(AjaxBehaviorEvent evt)
       {
        second=first*1000;
       }
```

Comment: JSF 2.0 has made Ajax pretty Kool :D

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The most you can do is to make an AJAX request. Similar question has been answered here, [How to access a java object in javascript from JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6577246/how-to-access-a-java-object-in-javascript-from-jsp/6577691#6577691)

Comment: How is Ajax different from JavaScript? It's after all just JavaScript, right?

Comment: @BalusC: I mean yes, but I don't say it calling a Java method from JavaScript, anyway. There are things involved in the middle, and we can't just simply say that Java method is called using JavaScript. What say you?