# Java Request Attributes to JavaScript Objects

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, request

I have a jQuery library that wants you to pass it a JavaScript object as an option. For example, this works:

```
//Hardcoded JavaScript object
var myData = { "A" : "1", "B" : "2", "C" : "3" };

//Call to jQuery with object as an option
$("#mySelectorId").myJqueryFunction({values: myData});
```

I need the `myData` object to not be hardwired like that.

I can easy get the "A to 1, B to 2, C to 3" structure in my Java code, put it in a `Map` (or some other object), and add it to the request via `request.setAttribute("myData", myMap);`. I am just not sure how to convert the `Map` (etc) into the needed JavaScript object. Here is what I have tried.

```
//Java
Map<String, String> myMap = new TreeMap<String, String>();
map.put("A", "1");
map.put("B", "2");
map.put("C", "3");
request.setAttribute("myMap", myMap);

//JSP
<c:set var="myData" value="{" />
<c:forEach var="mapEntry" items="${myMap}" varStatus="counter">
    <c:set var="myData" value="${myData}'${mapEntry.key}' : '${mapEntry.value}'" />
    <c:if test="${counter.count < fn:length(myMap)}">
        <c:set var="myData" value="${myData}, " />
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
<c:set var="myData" value="${myData}}" />

<script>
    var myData = '${myData}';
    $("#mySelectorId").myJqueryFunction({values: myData});
</script>
```

This works until the `myJqueryFunction` reaches a point where it tries to do something like this:

```
var i = values[code];
```

Essentially, it is trying to reference a particular variable on the object (e.g. trying to get the value of "B", which is 2). Note that `code` is a function parameter that holds the A/B/C value.

I have tried messing around with including or not including the quotes around `${mapEntry.key}` and things like that, but nothing seems to work.

Does anyone know how to get this working?

Comment: What does myData contain after the line `var myData = '${myData}';`?  Does `myData` contain a string or an object?  I don't have much knowledge of JSP but it looks like you might be assigning it a string.

Comment: It contains `{'A' : '1', 'B' : '2', 'C' : '3'}`. Verified via an `alert(myData);` call. The real issue with this question is whether the JSP variable is being correctly converted to a JavaScript OBJECT or not.

Comment: If `alert` shows that and not `[object Object]` then `myData` is a _String_.

Comment: Yep. Hence the question. How to make it one.

Comment: Does JSP require the single quotes? As in, is `var myData = ${myData};` valid? In JavaScript, single quotes mean strings, too, so you're effectively quoting your object.

Comment: It is not valid without the quotes.

Comment: I feel like the answer lies in the `eval` function somehow.

Comment: If you don't have any `undefined` or `function` properties, you can use `JSON.parse`, which is slightly safer than `eval` (assuming client supports it), or see http://stackoverflow.com/a/6577321/1615483

Comment: Tried all of them. Just get JavaScript errors. On IE 8 BTW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to use AJAX/JSON.

In a **NEW** controller (lets have it map to `/MyControllerUrl`), use a `List` and fill it with objects that have both the letter and the number of our objects (lets call this new object `MyClass`).

```
List<MyClass> myList = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
myList.add(new MyClass("A", "1"));
myList.add(new MyClass("B", "2"));
myList.add(new MyClass("C", "3"));
request.setAttribute("myList", myList);
```

The above is all that is in the new controller. And the returned JSP has only the following.

```
<c:out value="[" />

<c:forEach var="listItem" items="${myList}" varStatus="counter">
    {"letter": "${listItem.letter}", "number": "${listItem.number}"}<c:if test="${counter.count < fn:length(myList)}">,</c:if>
</c:forEach>

<c:out value="]" />
```

Finally, in the original JSP, have the following.

```
<script>
    var myJsList= { };
    $.ajax({
        url: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/MyControllerUrl',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(objectInfo) {
            $.each(objectInfo, function(key, object) {
                myJsList[object.code] = object.label;
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Note that I used `.ajax` instead of `.getJSON` so that I could set `async: false` so that the variable would be immediately ready for reference.

I don't love this option, as it requires 2 calls instead of 1. So I'll wait and see if there are any other ideas suggested.

Answer (score 0):

To add more properties (including by variable) in JavaScript, you can use this syntax

```
var myData = {}; // Initial object
myData["A"] = "1";
myData["B"] = "2";
myData["C"] = "3";
```

Then `myData` is `{ "A" : "1", "B" : "2", "C" : "3" }`.

Comment: This doesn't really help my situation. At least w/o further explaination.

Comment: Was suggesting a different way to construct `myData` so you didn't have the same issue, but if the answer is as simple as removing some quotes then this is overkill.

Comment: This did come into play in my AJAX solution. Ty.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've done JSP, but you're overriding your `myData` var in every iteration of your JSP `forEach` call, instead of concatenating to it. Second, your call to 'myJqueryFunction' is syntactically incorrect, instead of `values: myData` you probably want to use `{values: myData}`.

Third, you probably don't want to manually assemble a javascript object via JSP, there should be decent libraries out there that will do it for you.

Comment: On point 1, notice that `${myData}` is always in the setter value, so it is concatenating. I have done a `<c:out>` and all is well. On point 2, just a typo (this isn't my real code). I will fix my question text. On point 3, our company probably wouldn't allow any additional libraries, unless you know a well established one.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting myData as a string, and you can't remove the quotes around `'${myData}'` (which seems odd that you couldn't, BTW), then try this:

Change first line of JSP to this:

```
<c:set var="myData" value="var objMyData = {" />
```

And change your script to:

```
<script>
    var myData = '${myData}';
    eval(myData);
    $("#mySelectorId").myJqueryFunction({values: objMyData});
</script>
```