# Get model object returned from spring controller and assign it to global variable?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-3

I am using Spring3 MVC. I have a controller method which will return an object.
Now how can i get that object and assign it to global variable?

```
SomeObject uiInfo = new SomeObject("data","123");
return new ModelAndView("SomePage", "uiInfo", uiInfo);
```

Now how can i get this model in JSP and assign it to global variable?

Thanks!

Comment: You can reference it in the JSP with `${uiInfo}`. I'm not sure what you mean by assign it to a global variable.

Comment: My requirement is, i need to access this uiInfo inside an external JS file which is embedded in the same jsp file. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Return your model object to a view in your jsp's.

In your JSP you can use jstl tag library; something ike this,

```
<c:forEach var="global" items="${uiInfo}">
value1:  ${uiInfo.data1} <br/>
value2: ${uiInfo.data2} <br/>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: user, can i use this global variable in an external js which is embedded in same jsp?

Comment: yes, you can use it if you have declared the variable globally and not inside a specific function

Comment: where should i declare value1 and value2 variables?

Comment: value 1 and value 2 are just placeholders in your javascript object. you can give any name to it. It is just a name for your data inside the javascript object "global", you do not have to declare it.

Comment: now can i directly use value1 and value2 in external js?

Comment: No, you will have to send the variable "global" to your external js file because value1 and value2 are inside the "global" object.

Comment: To understand what i mean by sending JSP object to javascript file - check this link "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6577246/how-to-access-a-java-object-in-javascript-from-jsp"