# how to add Java Object in javascript array?

Tags: javascript, java

in jsp file.

```
    <% java.util.Vector <HighlightVO> conditions = bean.getPropVector("HighlightVOList");%>

    <script language="JavaScript">
    var conditions = []; 
        <% for(HighlightVO highlightVO : conditions){ %>
        conditions.push(<%=highlightVO%>); // not working.
        <%}%>

</script>
```

i am not able to add the highlighVO in conditions[].

Can any one help to do this operations.

Comment: Define `not working`. Is an error shown in your console ?

Comment: Refer the below link,this might helps [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6577246/how-to-access-a-java-object-in-javascript-from-jsp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6577246/how-to-access-a-java-object-in-javascript-from-jsp)

Comment: Invalid or unexpected token

Answer (score 1):

The parameters of javascript push must be understanded by javascript.
If you look at the javascript code generated, you will probably see something like :

```
    conditions.push(HighlightVO@6d06d69c)
```

which is not understanded by javascript.

A solution is to implement the toString() method of HighlightVO in order to return the object in json format.

Adding toString method in HighlightVO class :

```
  public String toString()
  {
    return '{'+
           'field1:'+field1+','+
           'field2:'+field2+','+
           ...
           '}';
  }
```

will generate :

```
conditions.push({field1:1,
                 field2:'2', ...})
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.