# (mybatis/JavaScript) bring data from DB and How to put the data on JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp, mybatis

Is there any way to put data from DB into the script?

I bring the data to JavaScript

```
<c:forEach var="map" items="${LHRankMap}">
   <tr>
        <td>${map.loca}</td>
        <!-- latitude -->
    <td>${map.la}</td>
        <!-- longitude-->
    <td>${map.lo}</td>
   </tr>  
</c:forEach>
```

[image]

It appears on the web well...
But I want to put the data to script

```
<script>
// I wnat to use loop for put my data(latitude, longitude) to below like that 
// var markerPosition  = new kakao.maps.LatLng(${map.la}, ${map.lo});

// this is the original code
var markerPosition  = new kakao.maps.LatLng(35.233242, 128.86656);
</script>
```

Is it possible?...

I tried to find some code on Google,
I couldn't find it...

Comment: Please, edit your question to keep it free from phrases like "it is hard for me", "please help!!!!", "sorry for bad explain..". In the tutorial [ask] they are called nothing other than noise because they have no relation to the question

Comment: @hayley Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6577321/1261766) help?